# Set maximum and minimum value of temperature and humidity that will be inserted to MySQL using Python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, arduino, sensors

I have some questions about how can we set a max/min value of temperature or humidity because sometimes during restart, the value of humidity suddenly spiked to >5000% or sometimes the temperature >100C.

So, I want to make sure that this data is not inserted to the SQL and filtered using python script added to the `.py`

Should I change this line?

```html
            if temp is not and hum is not None:
```

```html
import serial
import time
import pymysql.cursors
#Connect to database
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='ubuntu',
                             password='testing',
                             database='Blabla',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
print('Established serial connection to Arduino')
with connection:
    while True:
            arduino_data = arduino.readline()
            decoded_values = str(arduino_data[0:len(arduino_data)].decode("utf-8"))
            list_values = decoded_values.split(' ')
            print(f'Collected readings from Arduino: {list_values}')
            arduino_data = 0
            temp = list_values[0]
            hum = list_values[1]
            #Here we are going to insert the data into the Database
            if temp is not and hum is not None:
                with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `SensorTest` (`Temperature`, `Humidity`) VALUES (%s,%s)", (temp,hum))
                    connection.commit()
                    cursor.close()
            else:
                print('Failed to read the sensor')
            time.sleep(60)
```

[Img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kh7bJ.png)

[Img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxXjd.png)

Comment: [CHECK constraint](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html) will solve - it will prevent the insertion if the data does not match the constraint condition. And when insertion error occured you can analyse the value, define the reason and (if possible) fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can add more filters to this line to make sure the values are not wrong.

I would recommended setting const valid minimum and maximum values for both temp and hum at the start of the script (after the imports), for example:

```
MIN_VALID_TEMP = -20
MAX_VALID_TEMP = 90
MIN_VALID_HUM = 10
MAX_VALID_HUM = 1000
```

Next I would recommend splitting the temp and hum validation to an helper functions, such as:

```
def validate_reading(temp, hum):
    if not temp or not hum:
        return false
    if (temp > MIN_VALID_TEMP  and temp < MAX_VALID_TEMP and
    hum > MIN_VALID_HUM and hum < MAX_VALID_HUM):
        return true
    return false
```

and switch your original if:

```
if temp and hum is not None:
```

to:

```
if validate_reading(temp, hum):
```

Also what you can do next is to add a different print when the reading is not valid!

The final file will look like this:

```
import serial
import time
import pymysql.cursors

# define valid temp and hum
MIN_VALID_TEMP = -20
MAX_VALID_TEMP = 90
MIN_VALID_HUM = 10
MAX_VALID_HUM = 1000


def validate_reading(temp, hum):
    if not temp or not hum:
        return False
    if temp > MIN_VALID_TEMP and temp < MAX_VALID_TEMP and hum > MIN_VALID_HUM and hum < MAX_VALID_HUM:
        return True
    return False


# Connect to database
connection = pymysql.connect(
    host="localhost", user="ubuntu", password="testing", database="Blabla", cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
)
arduino = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0", 9600)
print("Established serial connection to Arduino")
with connection:
    while True:
        arduino_data = arduino.readline()
        decoded_values = str(arduino_data[0 : len(arduino_data)].decode("utf-8"))
        list_values = decoded_values.split(" ")
        print(f"Collected readings from Arduino: {list_values}")
        arduino_data = 0
        temp = list_values[0]
        hum = list_values[1]
        # Here we are going to insert the data into the Database
        if validate_reading(temp, hum):
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `SensorTest` (`Temperature`, `Humidity`) VALUES (%s,%s)", (temp, hum))
                connection.commit()
                cursor.close()
        else:
            print("Failed to read the sensor")
        time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: Hi Bukka, many thanks for answering!
I'm quite a newbie in python so..
so I've tried your answer i got the message
validate_reading(temp, hum):
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

do we need to do define the validate_reading? or?

Comment: @AkenFernando my bad you need to add 'def' at the start of the function when you define a function, I will edit my answer with the full file after my changes

Comment: hi @Bukka, yes i just use def and it's working! many thanks xD